Websocket gets disconnected when trying to connect IBM Watson Websocket to convert text to speech
I am using URLSessionWebSocketTask for connect websocket. i want to retain the websocket connection but unable to do so.

No one can give you an accurate answer without seeing error logs or your code. Try to create a [mre]

To better understand how this site works, take the  [tour] and read [ask]
